# How do I uninstall Live Messenger without uninstalling Windows Live Essentials?

Tags: windows, windows-live-messenger

Whenever I log on, Live Messenger pops up and asks me to sign in.  I don't have any friends that use Windows Live, so I don't need Live Messenger.  How do I uninstall Windows Live Messenger without uninstalling all of the Windows Live Essentials?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can go to Add/Remove Programs (or the Programs and Features section); when you select "Windows Live Essentials", the option is not Uninstall, it is "Uninstall/Change"

[image]

If you click Uninstall, you are able to choose the individual programs you wish to remove, in this case Windows Live Messenger.

[image]